# How do I have my repo take precedence over Maven

Tags: sbt

I've tried this

```
resolvers <<= resolvers.map { r =>
  Resolver.withDefaultResolvers(r ++ Seq(
    "my repository" at "http://example.com/repo"
  ), mavenCentral = false)
},
```

but it doesn't compile.

I'm actually not even sure how it is downloading from `repo1.maven.org`, since `sbt resolvers` doesn't list it (ever).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html) you need to change `resolvers` to `externalResolvers`.

> resolvers does not contain the default resolvers; only additional ones added by your build definition. sbt combines resolvers with some default repositories to form externalResolvers. Therefore, to change or remove the default resolvers, you would need to override externalResolvers instead of resolvers.